# Open Multiple files in Subfolders

Tags: vba

So far, I have been able to get the code to have all files opened in sub folders of the same name. The sub folder common name is June 2015, in the main "acquisitions" directory.

```
Sub DoFolderPart1()

    Dim FileSystem As Object
    Dim HostFolder As String

    HostFolder = "K:\Data Directories\Acquisitions"

    Set FileSystem = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
    DoFolder FileSystem.GetFolder(HostFolder)
End Sub

Sub DoFolder(Folder)
    Dim SubFolder
    Dim strName As String
    Dim pos As Integer

    For Each SubFolder In Folder.SubFolders

        DoFolder SubFolder

    Next

    Dim File
        strName = Folder.name
        pos = InStr(strName, "June 2015")
        If pos > 0 Then
            For Each File In Folder.Files
                If Right(File, 4) = "xlsx" Then
                    Workbooks.Open Filename:=File
                    'I want to put code here

                End If
            Next
       End If
End Sub
```

As can be seen, I was given this code by a kind person, but there was no comments on it. I'm quite new to VBA, and I'm having trouble figuring out why there are two different subs and what everything does.

I keep running into a problem where I can't perform any operations on the "File" after opening it. Any idea what could be causing this? For instance, there is a "type mismatch" error if I place Workbooks(File).Activate after "File" is opened. (This is just an example, as I am aware there are very few circumstance where .Activate should be used.)

Comment: what error do you receive?

Comment: Once it's open is it still a file object or can it be manipulated as just a workbook?

Comment: I get a "Type mismatch" error. Is seems referring to "File" as a workbook is what the problem is. If "File" is not a workbook type, what would it be? Is it a "file object" as justkrys suggested? And then why would the workbooks.open line work?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is `File` contains the *full path* of the file, not just the file name. You will need to extract the file name only if you want to reference it from the `Workbooks` Excel object:

```
If Right(File, 4) = "xlsx" Then
    Workbooks.Open fileName:=File
    'I want to put code here

    Dim fileName As String
    fileName = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject").GetFileName(File)

    Workbooks(fileName).Activate
    ' ... Do other stuff ...
End If
```

Comment: Ahhhh, that makes sense. Doing this: Set wb = Workbooks.Open(FileName:=File) also seemed to work to set the Workbook to a variable for use. Your explanation is great though!

Answer (score 1):

Added some comments to the code, to try to help.

As for working with the opened workbook, I would place `Dim wb as Workbook` at the top of the `DoFolder` sub and replace the line `Workbooks.Open Filename:=File` with `Set wb = Workbooks.Open(Filename:=File)`  Now `wb` is a workbook object, on which you can call `wb.Activate` or `wb.Worksheets` etc.

> ```
> Sub DoFolderPart1()
>
>     Dim FileSystem As Object
>     Dim HostFolder As String
>
>     HostFolder = "K:\Data Directories\Acquisitions"
>
>     Set FileSystem = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
>     DoFolder FileSystem.GetFolder(HostFolder)
> End Sub
>
> Sub DoFolder(Folder)
>     ' Declaring your variables
>     Dim SubFolder
>     Dim strName As String
>     Dim pos As Integer
>
>     ' Looping through your folders recursively
>     ' We go into each folder until we find a folder with only files
>     For Each SubFolder In Folder.SubFolders
>
>         DoFolder SubFolder
>
>     Next
>     ' If we find only files or we have already opened all of the subfolders
>     Dim File
>         strName = Folder.name   '<-- Store the folder name
>         ' Find the string "June 2015" in the folder name and store the
>         ' starting location as "pos"
>         pos = InStr(strName, "June 2015")
>         If pos > 0 Then                         '<-- If we found "June 2015"...
>             For Each File In Folder.Files'       <-- Go through each file
>                 If Right(File, 4) = "xlsx" Then '<-- if it's excel
>                     Workbooks.Open Filename:=File '    open it
>                     'I want to put code here
>
>                 End If
>             Next
>        End If
> End Sub
> ```

Chip Pearson has some [good guides](http://www.cpearson.com/excel/classes.aspx) for VBA:

Comment: Thanks for the help. Unfortunately wb = Workbooks.Open(Filename:=File) is still giving an "Object variable or With block variable not set" error. I have wb defined as a workbook in the sub

Comment: My fault.  When working with objects, one needs the `Set` keyword.  See correction.